# Select2 - How to set default value for "infinite scroll" example?

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm opening a form for editing some record. I'm using an "infinite scroll select2".

I want the input to show the option already saved to that field (I'm editing a record...)

How can I do that? This way is not working:

```
  $('#e7').select2('data', { id: 8, text: 'foo' });
```

I've created a jsfiddle to show that: http://jsfiddle.net/lucianocosta/Dyh8W/1/

Answer (score 1):

ivaynberg answered me: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/688#issuecomment-11971899

> you have to pass in an object that is in the same format as what your renderers expect. in this case the renderer you specified expects the title attribute, not text. see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dyh8W/2/

So the solution here is:

```
$('#e7').select2('data', { id: 8, title: 'foo' });
```